# Integral with $sin^3(\theta)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Me and one other person got this problem from a pdf online, $\int^{\pi/4}_0sin^3(\theta)d\theta$ The answer in the pdf is $2-\frac{5}{2\sqrt{2}}$ with a decimal value around $0.232233$. All of us are getting and answer that comes out to $0.07741$ or $(\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+\frac{2}{3}$.

We changed it to $sin^2sin$ and used $sin^2=1-cos$ and the then $u = cos$ and $du = -sin$to cancel out the remaining sin. And after doing the integration got $[\frac{cos^3(\theta)}{3}-cos(\theta)]^{\pi/4}_0$ and then our final answer of  $(\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+\frac{2}{3}$. We can't figure out hwo they got the other answer.

Comment: The answer in the pdf is wrong, you are correct. [Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28x%29^3+from+0+to+pi%2F4).

Comment: The answer in the pdf is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct and your answer is correct. The answer you have been provided is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sin ^{3}\theta ={\frac {3\sin \theta -\sin(3\theta )}{4}}\!$$